# ngx-translate custom loader doesn't find translations

Tags: angular, typescript, localization, internationalization, ngx-translate

I decided to implement custom loader for translations because I have an issue that string want to get translated before loader loads correct translations. I followed example on ngx-translate github but now everywhere I get keys instead of values. My custom loader:

```
    class CustomLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of({ KEY: 'value' });
  }
}
```

in app.module imports I have:

```
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: CustomLoader }
})
```

My translations are in ./assets/i18n/  and are all json. Anyone know what I need to change so loader will find my translations?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/locale-", ".json");
}
```

and then

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [Http]
      }
    })
```

Comment: but isn't this ordinary loader which is asynchronous? I would like to make one which is synchronous so I will be able to use translate.instant() method